# Text in inline-block div pushing it down

Tags: html, css

I discovered a strange CSS problem this morning and I'm hoping the CSS experts can help me out. In [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HBCe/), why is the text in the red div pushing it down? I expected that the two divs would be next to each other. Thanks!
EDIT: Thanks guys for the answers. I will accept an answer in a bit. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

...........................

Hi now used to  `vertical-align: top;`

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/7HBCe/5/)***

Comment: Can you explain why you did not use float:left , this is a clean solution.+1 for this.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best solution. Thanks! :) Do you know why the text caused that issue?

Comment: you can used to display inline-block that means by defulat inline-block is baseline than define to always vertical-align top  if you define display inline-block element in any html element .

Comment: oh thank you. I could not for the life of me figure out why all the browsers were drawing these boxes (inline-block) at different heights! I was about to cave and use absolute positioning...

Answer (score -3):

Adding `float:left` solves the issue.

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7HBCe/)**

Comment: I think it would be interesting to know why it is working this way with text.

Comment: @TimotheeTosi I noticed that , I don't know why , can you let me know.Thanks.

Comment: "inline-block tells browsers to place that ele­ment inline, but to treat it as though it were a block level ele­ment." So you can float it! http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

Comment: `float: left` cause this [Click the link to view the image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gYRqS.jpg)